# Unload from Redshift to S3: Authentication not working

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am using the following script:

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM table WHERE
UPPER(description) LIKE \'%something%\' AND
transaction_date=\'2014-01-01\'')
TO 's3://yourdirectory/jan14.txt' CREDENTIALS 
'aws_access_key_id=xxxx;
aws_secret_access_key=xxx'
PARALLEL OFF
```

But it returns this error:

An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM yi_base_views.card_panel WHERE
UPPER(description) LIKE \'%LULULEMON%\' AND
transaction_date=\'2014-01-01\'')
TO 's3://yourdirec...

ERROR: Invalid credentials. Must be of the format: credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key=[;token=]'
  Detail:

---

error:  Invalid credentials. Must be of the format: credentials 'aws_access_key_id=;aws_secret_access_key=[;token=]'
  code:      8001
  context:
  query:     0
  location:  aws_credentials_parser.cpp:59
  process:   padbmaster [pid=43295]

---

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line break between the access key and secret key and it should work.